# Order of data type in Structure

Tags: c, data-structures

My structure is,

```
typedef struct {
  uint16 a;
  uint16 b;
  uint8  c[8];
  uint8  d;
  uint8  e;
}subset_t;

typedef struct node{
   subset_t list;
   struct node *link;
}all_list
```

After adding list, I am displaying. For example adding elements are:

```
a = 112, b = 341, c = AB321EF6, d = 1, e = 2.
```

If I display, every thing is fine except for `c`: it displays `AB321EF61N`.

But if I change the structure to:

```
typedef struct {
      uint16 a;
      uint16 b;
      uint8  d;
      uint8  e;
      uint8  c[8];
    }subset_t;
```

Then I am getting exact result. As I know, higher data type should be given first. Some one tell why arrays should be last.

Comment: Arrays definitely don't *have to* be last. Can you provide [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing these results?

Comment: You can't expect to store 8 characters plus a terminating null byte into a `char c[8];` member of a structure.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that arrays need to be last, it's that you need a NULL terminator on your array if you want to be able to print it out as a string (with `%s` format specifier). Redefine c as `uint8 c[9]` and set the last element (`c[8]`) to 0.

Comment: Or use `"%.8s"` to limit the printing to the first 8 characters.  But you're right that the string is not null terminated (and can't be with a `char c[8]` field holding 8 characters.  I expect that it would 'work' for `c` and fail for `d` if the code assigned 1 to `d` and then copied the string to `c` (`d` would appear to be 0 instead of 1).

Answer (score 1):

You should show more code.

I guess the "strange" results you're getting are because you're hitting undefined behavior.

You cannot store "AB321EF6" in `char c[8]` since the string doesn't fit, there's no room for the terminator. Thus, your printing runs off the end of `c`, and depending on the rest of the structure's memory layout might or might not hit a terminator. This is undefined behavior.